# Crash using Animated Vector Drawable - Device running 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-vectordrawable

I get the following crash  when using animated vector drawable - my setup is

Devices tested on Nougat 7.1.1 - Oneplus 3 , Oneplus one , Nexus 6 (api 25) emulator

My code was working fine earlier , now it seems to be broken , I'm Unable to start my Activity.

```
// Sdk and tools
minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 25
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = '25.0.1'

// Java
targetJVM = 1.8

// App dependencies
supportLibraryVersion = '25.1.1'


 Process: techgravy.nextstop, PID: 30215

                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{techgravy.nextstop/techgravy.nextstop.ui.search.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Could not instantiate class android.transition.Transition class techgravy.nextstop.ui.transitions.StartAnimatable
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Could not instantiate class android.transition.Transition class techgravy.nextstop.ui.transitions.StartAnimatable
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createCustom(TransitionInflater.java:227)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:171)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:185)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:79)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getTransition(PhoneWindow.java:2799)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2762)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:413)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2444)
                                                                    at techgravy.nextstop.ui.search.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:120)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createCustom(TransitionInflater.java:218)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:171) 
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:185) 
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:79) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getTransition(PhoneWindow.java:2799) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2762) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:413) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2444) 
                                                                    at techgravy.nextstop.ui.search.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:120) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable techgravy.nextstop:drawable/avd_back_to_search with resource ID #0x7f02005b
                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/avd_back_to_search.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005b
                                                                    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
                                                                    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                    at techgravy.nextstop.ui.transitions.StartAnimatable.<init>(StartAnimatable.java:54)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createCustom(TransitionInflater.java:218)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:171)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml(TransitionInflater.java:185)
                                                                    at android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition(TransitionInflater.java:79)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getTransition(PhoneWindow.java:2799)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2762)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:413)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2444)
                                                                    at techgravy.nextstop.ui.search.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:120)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6760)
03-18 21:08:32.840 30215-30215/techgravy.nextstop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2681)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6290)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:471)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
                                                                        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
                                                                            ... 27 more


   res/drawable/avd_back_to_search.xml
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/searchback_back">

    <target
        android:name="arrow_head"
        android:animation="@animator/searchback_hide_arrow_head_move" />

    <target
        android:name="arrow_head_top"
        android:animation="@animator/searchback_hide_arrow_head" />

    <target
        android:name="arrow_head_bottom"
        android:animation="@animator/searchback_hide_arrow_head" />

    <target
        android:name="stem"
        android:animation="@animator/searchback_stem_back_to_search" />

    <target
        android:name="search_circle"
        android:animation="@animator/searchback_show_circle" />

</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Will add more details - code/ usage if required

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable techgravy.nextstop:drawable/avd_back_to_search with resource ID #0x7f02005b
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/avd_back_to_search.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005b

Comment: I have the file in the path (res/drawable/avd_back_to_search.xml)

Comment: Can it be cause of     multiDexEnabled true

Comment: I have similar named png in drawable-hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi etc